# Cor de fundo não saiu ao clicar no botão de fechar CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web utilizando Html,CSS,Jquery, e toda vez que a a pagina é carregada aparece um modal com uma imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando eu clico no icone de fechar a imagem sai mas a cor de fundo não.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
<div id="boxes">
<div id="dialog" class="window">
<a href="#" class="close">x</a><br />
    <!-- Adicione o nome da imagem aqui -->
<img width="300" src="imagens/bolos.JPG" border="0">
</div>
<!-- Máscara para cobrir a tela -->
<div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(window).load(function() {
$('#dialog').modal('show');


  });

    $( "#close" ).click(function() {
   $("#mask").css("display", "none");
});

  $(document).ready(function() {  

    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
            //Escolha a opacidade do fundo
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Obeter o tamanho da janela
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
    $(id).fadeIn(1000); 

});

$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
       $('.window').hide();
    });         

 });
```

CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">

a {color:#333; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:#ccc; text-decoration:none}

    #mask {
   position:absolute;
  left:0;
 top:0;
 z-index:9000;
 background-color:#aaa2a2;
 display:none;
 }

  #boxes .window {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
  width:0px;
 height:0px;
 display:none;
 z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
 }

#boxes #dialog {
 position:absolute;
 width:675px;
 height:453px;
 padding:10px;
left: 80%;

}

  .close{

  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-top: 4px;
  right: 50%;
 }

  </style>
```

Erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem 3 problemas no seu código:

**1º. Troque**

`$("#mask").css("display", "none");` por `$('#dialog').modal('hide');`

> Na verdade, essa `<div id="mask"></div>` não está tendo nenhuma
>   utilidade. O próprio Bootstrap já tem nativa um fundo transparente
>   para a modal.

**2º. Troque**

```
$( "#close" ).click(function() {
```

Por:

```
$( ".close" ).click(function() {
```

O `close` é um `class` e não um `id`.

Então essa parte do código fica assim:

```
$( ".close" ).click(function() {
   $('#dialog').modal('hide');
});
```

**3º. Troque:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#dialog').modal('show');
});
```

Por:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
   $('#dialog').modal('show');
});
```

**Exemplo para referência:**

```js
$(window).on('load',function() {
   $('#dialog').modal('show');
});

$(document).on('click', '.close, .modal-backdrop',function() {
   $('#dialog').modal('hide');
});
```

```css
a {color:#333; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:#ccc; text-decoration:none}

#boxes #dialog {
   position:absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   z-index: 999999;
}

.close{
   color: #fff;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   right: -20px;
   top: -20px;
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="boxes">
   <div id="dialog">
      <a href="#" class="close">x</a>
         <!-- Adicione o nome da imagem aqui -->
         <img width="300" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" border="0">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: eu tirei a <div id="mask"></div>, fiz as alterações que você me falou mas continuou o mesmo erro

Comment: @User1999 Editei a resposta

Comment: continuou o mesmo erro

Comment: o estranho que funciona quando eu não clico no <a href="#" class="close">x</a><br /> ai a imagem sai e o fundo sai tb

Comment: @User1999 Alterei todo o CSS e o JS. Agora acho que está mais funcional.

Comment: era isso mesmo obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você não informou qual Plugin Modal esta utilizando ou se esta utilizando o Modal do **jQuery UI**... de toda forma você esta iniciando a Janela via **JavaScript** e fechando via **CSS**, isso ai esta na contra mão... você tem que entender a estrutura de funcionamento da classe `modal()` para encerrar essa janela via **CSS**, se você esta usando o método `'show'` da classe modal, utilize o método `'close'` da classe também uai:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
```

Isso já esta pronto na classe pra você utilizar, não precisa encerrar via CSS, fazendo isso você vai esta duplicando código de forma desnecessária.

Comment: fiz as alterações , mas o erro continuou, não sai a cor de fundo preta quando eu fecho  o modal